# Modify data before jquery ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a form that is used by admin to modify user details and before submitting I want to modify the structure of the data ( flat array) to be a json objects with some level of hierarchy.

```
User = { username: 'myUserName' , roles : [ {role : 'ADMIN'},{role: USER} ], etc..}
```

so to do this in my client web page I've done this :

```
$("#submitUpdate").click(function() {
            var dataAsJson = JSON.stringify(function(){
                //user
                var o = {};
                //spring token
                var tk = {};
                //var usrname
                var un={};
                var formData = $("#updateForm").serializeArray();
                $.each(formData, function(k, v) {
                    if (o[v.name] !== undefined) {
                        if (!o[v.name].push) {
                            o[v.name] = [ o[v.name] ];
                        }
                        o[v.name].push(v.value || '');
                    } else {
                        if (v.name === 'userRoles') {
                            if (v.value !== undefined) {
                                var a = [];
                                $.each(v.value.split(','), function(i, rl) {
                                    var r = {};
                                    r.role = rl;
                                    a.push(r);
                                });
                                o[v.name] = a;
                            } else
                                o[v.name] = [];
                        } else if (v.name === '_csrf') {
                            tk[v.name] = v.value;
                        } else if (v.name === '_username') {
                            un[v.name] = v.value || '';
                        } else
                            o[v.name] = v.value || '';
                    }
                });
                var obj = [];
                obj.push(tk);   obj.push(un);   obj.push(o);
                return  obj;
            }());

            $("#updateForm").ajaxSubmit({
                url : "${userUpdateCtx}",
                data: dataAsJson,
                beforeSubmit : function(formData, jqForm, options) {

                },
                success : function(msg) {
                    $table.bootstrapTable('refresh');
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    showError(e);
                }
            });
        });
```

the problem is that the for is never gets submit and I get **ERROR 400**

```
HTTP Status 400 -
Type Report Status
message
Description request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

I've tried to put the processing code inside `beforeSubmit` and return the string `JSON.stringify(obj)` but this don't seem to work either.

how could I make this work ?.

**EDIT**

Thanks to comments below I've fixed the `dataAsJson` but still having the same error, the dump of the request looks like this (cut it off too long ):

```
URL de la requête :     http://localhost:8080/WebMarket/admin/users/update?_csrf=9323a5ac-9a49-436f-a799-89b4814fb309&enabled=1&firstName=Steve&lastName=Jobs&_username=manager&username=manager&password=%242a%2410%24BVRCqPA6.qdvs%2Fma0uH6Here4ozKudoHyH2OFz2xc3.FfwL%2FEyXz6&userRoles=ROLE_MANAGER&0=%5B&1=%7B&2=%22&3=_&4=c&5=s&6=r&7=f&8=%22&9=%3A&10=%22&11=9&12=3&13=2&14=3&15=a&16=5&17=a&18=c&19=-&20=9&21=a&22=4&23= 
Méthode de la requête :     POST
Code d'état :   HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
```

Comment: You probably have a couple of different things going on here, but the one that is the easiest to identify is that your dataAsJSON is trying to stringify the functionbody, rather than the function result. I.e. function (){} vs function(){}().   formData is also undefined in beforeSubmit.

Comment: you better provide your full code in fiddle , excluding ajax call .

Comment: @visibleman Thanks for the hint, indeed the 'dataAsJson' now is not empty but I still getting the error HTTP 400.

Comment: @JSantosh In fact the form was working mode like with a submit button ( not in ajax mode ) but I needed ajax since I have to send data as json to be processed by my application server ( Ihave a spring mvc based app )